# Calysto Hy not starting properly

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, hy

I have run an intro to Hy session for the Atlanta Functional Programming meetup.

One audience for this intro is Pythonistas that might want to use Hy to get acquainted with a Lispy syntax by porting their python projects to Hy.

Since Jupyter is popular with Pythonistas (I use it a lot to do exploratory coding when I write Python), I'd like to use Calysto Hy kernel.

When I select the Calysto Hy tile in Jupyter lab, in the terminal from which I launched Jupyter, I see the following message repeating a lot, and code is not executed in Jupyter:

```
[I 20:36:29.895 LabApp] Kernel started: cb8848bf-491e-4502-96fa-8089b8aca66d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/calysto_hy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .kernel import CalystoHy
  File "/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/calysto_hy/kernel.py", line 13, in <module>
    from hy.macros import _hy_macros, load_macros
ImportError: cannot import name '_hy_macros' from 'hy.macros' (/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hy/macros.py)
```

When I open `/home/gt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hy/macros.py` in trusty ol' emacs, I see nothing named `_hy_macros`.

I'd appreciate any help I can get in getting calysto Hy to work.

I have another teaching session coming up in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Make sure that you're using compatible versions of Jupyter, Calysto, Hy, and Python. If you are, it's probably a Calysto bug.

Comment: That certainly makes sense.  Is there authoritative info about fruitful combinations?

Comment: -- I'll edit this comment in a bit ---

Comment: OK.  I am using

`Calysto-Hy 0.1.1`,
`Hy 0.19.0`, and

`jupyter core     : 4.6.3`
`jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3`
`qtconsole        : 4.7.0`
`ipython          : 7.13.0`
`ipykernel        : 5.1.4`
`jupyter client   : 6.0.0`
`jupyter lab      : 2.0.0`
`nbconvert        : 5.6.1`
`ipywidgets       : 7.5.1`
`nbformat         : 5.0.4`
`traitlets        : 4.3.3`

 @Kodiologist

Comment: I don't know what a good combination of versions is because I've never used Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Do you use other such notebooks?  I appreciate your time. @kodiologist

Comment: I just use Org-mode.

Comment: OK.  I used org mode for a presentation I recently did for Atlanta Functional Programming meetup.  I know a lot of students of the DS track at Lambda School, and they use the python ecosystem.  Mark Watson wrote a book on his use of Hy to carry out DS work.  Hey, do you have an example of a good use of defmacro in Hy?

Comment: https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/whyhy.html#do-while